# Why PHP executes differently in relatively similar environments

Tags: php, wordpress

For some reason

```
namespace yd_custom_hero_cards {
    if (!is_plugin_active('yd-hero-cards/plugin.php')) {
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', '\yd_custom_hero_cards\load_custom_bbhc_user_styles');
    }
}
```

works fine in a docker instance but returns

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function yd_custom_hero_cards\is_plugin_active() in ...
```

on another, non containerised, host. PHP is the same version (7.4) and I compared the setup and it is relatively the same. The error shows up when either trying to work with wp cli or accessing the page through a browser.

If I remove the code, I get warnings like:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in ...
```

even though there are no missing closing statements (curly braces or endif and so on).

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a starting php tag in the file? `<?php`

Comment: If you get a parse error, it's because there's a parse error. If you get 'undefined function' error it's because the code defining the function hasn't been included. Whatever defines `is_plugin_active` has not been included into the codebase.

Comment: Yes, there is an opening tag and no closing tag with one empty line at the end of the file. All the other opening tags are being matched by a closing tag.

Comment: @miken32 it is a WordPress setup. The function is defined in the WordPress files.

Comment: As I mentioned, the code works fine on one machine but breaks on another. Even though  short_open_tag is enabled on both.

Comment: Closing tags are not needed, and are not recommended unless you need to output HTML after the PHP code completes. Don't enable `short_open_tag`, and be immediately suspicious of any code that uses short open tags; it's probably a decade old.

Comment: @miken32 By closing tags I meant the ones which SHOULD match the open tags. As I mentioned, there is no closing tag at the end of the file. I had to enable short_open_tag since there is some code requiring it. But I agree that is bad practice in general. thx